# Can you fit every single permutation of a triangle inside a circle with all three points touching the edges of the circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I am having a heated debate with some colleagues about this. I don't think that you can, but am unsure on how to prove this whereas other people think you always can but again cannot prove it. Is there a proof out there for this?

By permutations I mean any type of triangle with varying length of side and varying angle size.

I think I have proven it cannot be done using a right angled triangle.

Comment: What do you mean by permutation (i.e. rotation/flipping) and what kind of triangle (i.e equilateral)?

Comment: The statement is not clear. What are the permutations of a triangle? The circle is fixed?

Comment: You might be interested in the following observation, which may relate to your question. Every triangle fits in its own circumcircle. If you have two different triangles you can scale by similarity so that the circumradii are equal. Then they fit in the same circle.

Comment: As to the right angle case:  Every right triangle can be circumscribed in a circle wherein the hypotenuse is a diameter.

Answer (score 3):

Every triangle can be circumscribed by a circle. To see this, given a triangle $ABC$, note that the centre of the circle, $O$, by definition must be equidistant from the three points. Thus to construct the circle, draw the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ as well as the perpendicular bisector of $AC$; their intersection gives you $O$.